# What are these extra instructions when disassembling simple binary?

Tags: gcc, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, objdump

this is a bit of a noobish question... Here's a quick bit of background.
I'm learning about assembly, so I wrote a really simple C program, compiled it with `gcc -m32 -O0 -o prog.elf` and then ran objdump against it with `objdump -M intel -d prog.elf`.

The C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    a = a + b;

    return (0);
}
```

Which seems simple enough. The generated Intel assembly (with my comments) is:

```
push   ebp                       ; Push previous stack frame.
mov    ebp, esp                  ; Move SP to EBP to set new stack frame.
sub    esp, 0xc                  ; Reserve 0xc bytes for local variables.
xor    eax, eax                  ; Clear eax.
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4], 0x0  ; Move 0x0 into local variable ebp-0x4.
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8], 0x1  ; Move 0x1 into local variable ebp-0x8.
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc], 0x2  ; Move 0x2 into local variable ebp-0xc.
mov    ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]  ; Move local variable ebp-0x8 into ecx.
add    ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]  ; Add local variable ebp-0xc to ecx.
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8], ecx  ; Move value of ecx into local variable ebp-0x8.
add    esp, 0xc                  ; Set SP back to location before.
pop    ebp                       ; Restore base pointer.
ret                              ; Return
```

*My question* is, what is **ebp-0x4** doing there? It doesn't seem to be doing anything.
I'll take a guess and say it's from main()'s paramaters, which it doesn't have, but for some reason it still pushes 0x0 as a parameter if none are provided?
Also, why **xor eax, eax** doesn't seem to be used...

I'm just a little confused about why they're there.
If anyone can help me understand why that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a different version of gcc than I do apparently, I get different results.  I am curious if you change you return value to something different, say a 7 or something does the ebp-0x04 change to that value.  It wouldnt surprise me that being unoptimized they have reserved a location for the return value on the stack and set it, but dont actually use it.

Comment: You're compiling without optimizations. Of course the compiler is going to do pointless things when you don't allow it to optimize its code.

Comment: @old_timer I still get ebp-0x4 being initialised to 0, even if I return a, haha. I think it must be a compiler artefact like paxdiablo said.

Comment: @Michael Petch LLVM 8.0 on OSX, hahaha.

Comment: What version of OS/X is that on? Some of those compilers on OS/X (the ones installed by default) can be pretty old. As was mentioned it is likely just an artifact of the code generator. Turning on optimizations may see it disappear.

Comment: @Michael Petch Seirra 10.12.3. Ahhh, yeah. Thanks for the information.

Comment: LLVM 7.0 on a slightly older version of OS/X generates similar. Sometimes there is an obvious reason for the artifacts. It was just a curiosity to me - thanks. A similar thing gets generated if you reduce it to just `return(0)`

Comment: @Michael Petch Ahhh, okay, no problem!

Comment: Another interesting thing. It seems that instruction is generated for the function `main`. If you take the same instructions and put it in a function `foo` I noticed the MOV to ebp-4 isn't done.

Comment: @Michael Petch Oh strange, that's interesting.

Comment: With optimizations turned on, this code turns into two instructions: `xor eax, eax`, followed by `ret`. If you changed it to `return a`, then this code would turn into `mov eax, 3` followed by `ret`. If your compiler is not generating that code, then your compiler sucks and you should get a new one. (Or just turn on optimizations. FYI, analyzing disassembly of unoptimized code is largely a waste of time.)

Comment: GCC has some weird rules for the `main` function. It disables a *lot* of optimizations for `main`, even when you have optimizations enabled. That's probably connected to why you're getting the pointless store of 0 to `ebp-4`, and also explains why Michael Petch isn't seeing it when the same code is in functions other than `main`.

Comment: @CodyGray : I forgot to revisit this. I didn't mention that I was able to get rid of zeroing of that memory location on the stack in `main` by making `main` return void rather than `int` and replace `return (0)` with `return`. Of course I'm violating the signature for main and had to override it with ` -Wno-main-return-type` . The move to `ebp-4` disappears. This was on a hunch that the memory location (in unoptimized code) likely had something to do with the return value from `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure as to why you think `xor eax, eax` is not being used, this is a simple way to set `eax` to zero. Since it's often the return code from a function, it would be the equivalent of your `return 0;` (which doesn't need parentheses by the way).

As to why the `ebp-0x4` is there, I couldn't say. I *will* say that the rest of the code is well and truly unoptimised so it may just be an artefact of the compilation process. It may well disappear at higher optimisation levels, especially since the entire function could basically be replaced with the one line you think is superfluous :-)

Comment: I kind of forgot eax would be used to return, haha. That makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @needshelpwithassembly You should probably return a, not 0.

Comment: @JeremyP Thanks, but I just wanted to deal will a few simple instructions, not having to deal with the whole return process, but I'm working on understanding that now. :)

Comment: @needshelpwithassembly The reason I suggested it was so that any optimisation doesn't take out stuff you want to look at. Also, you get to see how `return` works.